# Copy Webpage to Clipboard automatically

Tags: python, python-2.7, clipboard

Is it posible to copy a web page (whatever I see, not the source) onto a clipboard automatically (without using ctrl+c), using python / javascript.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to extract the usable text from a web page, you can use something like [BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172343/extracting-readable-text-from-html-using-python). If you want to copy it to the clipboard, you can use [pyperclip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4308279/125377).